# Can I overload function templates based on properties?

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I want to get a common property from different families of classes. For some, I can just use a member, for some I need to call a function.
Can I overload template functions in a way so that the compiler chooses the fitting template function based on whether the class has `functionA`, `functionB` or `member`? Currently I get errors because I define the same template function multiple times...

```
template<class TypeWithFunctionA>
int doSomething(const TypeWithFunctionA & h)
{
  return h.functionA();
}

template<class TypeWithFunctionB>
int doSomething(const TypeWithFunctionB & h)
{
  return h.functionB();
}

template<class TypeWithMember>
int doSomething(const TypeWithMember & h)
{
  return h.member;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can overload them with [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae). e.g.

```
template<class TypeWithFunctionA>
auto doSomething(const TypeWithFunctionA & h) -> decltype(h.functionA())
{
  return h.functionA();
}

template<class TypeWithFunctionB>
auto doSomething(const TypeWithFunctionB & h) -> decltype(h.functionB())
{
  return h.functionB();
}

template<class TypeWithMember>
auto doSomething(const TypeWithMember & h) -> decltype(h.member)
{
  return h.member;
}
```

Comment: Does this also work if I don't return an int but a const reference to say a std::string? If h.member is a std::string, then the string will be copied which I would like to avoid.

Comment: @Fabian You have to specify the return type as `-> const decltype(h.member)&`.

Answer (score 2):

C++20 makes this very straignforward:

```
template <class TypeWithFunctionA>
int doSomething(const TypeWithFunctionA &h)
requires requires{h.functionA();}
{
    return h.functionA();
}

template <class TypeWithFunctionB>
int doSomething(const TypeWithFunctionB &h)
requires requires{h.functionB();}
{
    return h.functionB();
}

template <class TypeWithMember>
int doSomething(const TypeWithMember &h)
requires requires{h.member;}
{
    return h.member;
}
```